# How to iterate over a date range in the following format 25-12-2012 to 31-12-2012(hyphen should be maintained) in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, date, datetime

I want to handle the leap years Feb 29 cases as well.

I tried the following, but having trouble in converting each time format to dd-mm-yyyy.

```
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

Date start = sdfd.parse("26-02-1989");
Date end = sdfd.parse("06-03-1989");

gcal.setTime(start);

while (gcal.getTime().before(end)) 
{
    gcal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println( gcal.getTime().toString());
    System.out.println(gcal.);
}
```

I am also fine with using Javascript engine inside Java.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are entirely different languages. Which do you want (I suspect Java)?

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` is the wrong type for this. It has millisecond (not day) precision. [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is more appropriate. Use [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) if you need Java <8 compatibility.

To format a `LocalDate`:

```
localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` object is simply a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, the format is irrlevent.

The `Date`'s `toString` method simply uses the system local to provide a human readable representation of it's content.  You can not modify this format (directly and nor should you, because it will change on the next machine you run your code on)

If you want to display the `Date` in a given format then you should use an appropriate formatter, for example...

```
System.out.println( sdfd.format(gcal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Date-Only

The [answer by Chris Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877895/642706) is correct. If you are not comparing the beginning/ending of days across time zones, then you can use a class for date-only without any time-of-day or time zone component.

## `Joda-Time` & `java.time`

In addition to the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), you can use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which inspired java.time. Both java.time and Joda-Time offer a `LocalDate` class. Both frameworks have their strengths and weaknesses. You can use both frameworks in a project if you are careful with your `import` statements.

## Example Code

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );

// LocalDate start = formatter.parseLocalDate( "26-02-1989" );
LocalDate start = new LocalDate( 1989, 2, 26 );
LocalDate stop = new LocalDate( 1989, 3, 6 );
LocalDate localDate = start;
while ( localDate.isBefore( stop ) )
{
    String output = formatter.print( localDate );
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

Comment: I prefer the JSR-310 backport for easier migration to Java 8. Why do you recommend Joda?

Comment: As I said, Joda-Time and java.time each have their pros and cons. From what I've seen so far, neither is superior to the other. Imagine a [Venn diagram](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_o6vigEr23C4/SRxvux__cyI/AAAAAAAAAK4/8FPHJYHUmao/s400/venn.jpg), with some shared functionality but each offering something the other does not. Note the [ThreeTen-Extra project](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) to fill out some additional areas of functionality in java.time.